# Reference all files in a group or folder in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to know if I create a group or folder full of files, like images, say img1.jpg, img1@2x.jpg, img2.jpg, img2@2x.jpg ... img10.jpg, img10@2x.jpg, is there a way to create an array of all these images dynamically without knowing how many images are there? Basically, I want something dynamic so it will find all the new images if I add more without having to also update my code. Can this be done?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Find them in your app or find them in xCode?

Comment: Are you downloading the images from somewhere? If you are then store them in an NSMUtableArray. That's what it's for to store an unknown number of items. You don't need folders nore do you need to save them.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately XCode does not have that feature, however if you are willing to manually increment a constant, you can easily do some string manipulation to get an array:

```
#define IMAGE_COUNT 10
#define PREFIX @"img"

NSMutableArray *images, *images2x;
images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];
images2x = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];

for(int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++){
    NSString *imagePath = [PREFIX stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d.jpg",i];
    NSString *image2xPath = [PREFIX stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d@2x.jpg",i];

    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imagePath]];
    [images2x addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:image2xPath]];
}
```

you are manually adding the files and they are all numbered so it can't hurt to simply change IMAGE_COUNT every time you add an image.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might be the best approach. Unfortunately, I can't find anything completely dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

To make xCode automatically detect new images you need to add the folder that contains those images "as reference".  When clicking and dragging the image folder into xCode it will pop up with an import window.  One of the radial buttons will have the option "Add as reference."  Select that one and the folder will be auto updated with anything that you add into it.  You may have to clean and rebuild the project in order for xCode to actually send those updates to your app.

To do it in your app (in code) you would do something like:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:yourFolderPath error:&error];
```

That will give you an array of NSStrings containing the names of all the files and folders inside the selected folder.  If you need subfolders too then you are going to have to do recursive calls.